# Unable to override the overflow css property from external file

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, jquery-chosen

I am trying to override the `overflow` css property. This value is set as below in an external file which I am including.

```
#bodyWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I tried to override this value by setting it in inline style tag as `style="overflow:none"`, but this is not having any effect.

I tried to override by jquery as `$("#bodyWrapper").css("overflow", "none")`, but still no effect.

Here is the screenshot what that is causing. When I remove the `overflow:hidden` from firebug, it works as expected.
[image]

Here is jsFiddle having this issue. http://jsfiddle.net/HZUeF/4/

Select both options in first drop down and try to select an option in below drop down.

Comment: try style="overflow:none !important;"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`none` isn't a valid value for the [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-overflow) property; use the initial value, `visible` instead.

```
$("#bodyWrapper").css("overflow", "visible")
```

Comment: notice the right property value to 'visible' and not 'none', you may not even need javascript (as jQuery) to overwrite this value.